# Ipyaggrid - Dataframe edit function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grid, ag-grid

I need to modify my df using aggrid edit function. The issue I face is that when I do the changes in the "grid interface" I can either export to csv or excel(with a button) but I would like to apply the modification to the existing df. Any possibility to do it ?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from ipyaggrid import Grid 
data = np.array([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)],
                dtype=[("a", "i4"), ("b", "i4"), ("c", "i4")])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['c', 'a'])
def simple_grid(df):

    column_defs = [{'headername':c,'field': c} for c in df.columns]

    grid_options = {
        'columnDefs' : column_defs,
        'enableSorting': True,
        'enableFilter': True,
        'enableColResize': True,
        'enableRangeSelection': True,
        'rowSelection': 'multiple',
    }

    g = Grid(grid_data=df,
             grid_options=grid_options,
             quick_filter=True,
             show_toggle_edit=True,
             sync_on_edit=True,
             export_csv=True,
             export_excel=True,
             export_to_df=True,
             theme='ag-theme-balham',
             show_toggle_delete=True,
             columns_fit='auto',
             index=False)
    return g
    simple_grid(df)
df
```

Comment: This seems to be the sole question related to Ipyaggrid on stackoverflow [Python].

Answer (score 0):

```
g = simple_grid(df)
print(g)

#make your changes, then in a new cell...

dfUpdated = g.grid_data_out.get('grid')
print(dfUpdated)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.